# Facebook API, Phone Numbers

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

I am developing a Facebook Application that I need to get all the information of user, including mobile phone. However, even this page claims https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/446 that `user_mobile_phone` permission exists, neither the documentation includes a field of mobile phone number. I am creating a synchronization of contacts, so the phone field is very important.

Why this is blocked? Spamming with mobile is not a very nice spamming approach, it has a cost. They even let e-mails to be given (although you can change it to a cloaking address), but we cannot get phone numbers or addresses.

Is there a way to get it via an app?

EDIT: Even this: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/447

Comment: I haven't heard or seen anything about the elusive mobile phone permissions for quite a while, and features like SMS were phased out with the introduction of the Graph API, so I would just assume that a dedicated field for this information is AWOL indefinitely.

Comment: Perhaps you might have success with some Regular Expression searching through the other users' fields, looking for phone number formatted text.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/01/14/platform-updates--new-user-object-fields--edge-remove-event-and-more/

say:
Update: The user_address and user_mobile_phone permissions have been removed. Please see this post for more info.

Comment: So in short we cannot get User mobile no ? or is there any method or permission they introduce ?