# Facebook , How to get phone number after login with facebook sdk?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have integrated FB sdk for customer login and not able to get phone number in response.
Here is my code

```
FB.api('/me',
    {fields: "id,email,first_name,gender,name,last_name,token_for_business"},
      function(response) {

    });
```

With that above code, I am getting all information expect phone number. I have passed extra parameter **mobile_phone** then getting undefined response.
Here is code

```
FB.api('/me',
    {fields: "id,email,first_name,gender,name,last_name,token_for_business,mobile_phone"},
      function(response) {
      console.log(response.mobile_phone);
    });
```

I have tried with parameter "user_mobile_phone" also still getting undefined response only

Please help me to resolve this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

There is no way to get the phone number, those phone permissions do not exist.

There are other threads about this already, for example: [Facebook API, Phone Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563786/facebook-api-phone-numbers)

Comment: Can we get explicitly passing phone number parameter in request?

Comment: please read my answer again: "there is no way". there´s not even a permission for the phone number.

Comment: Thanks luschn , 
Suppose i have registered FB with phone number then also we can't get phone number information ?

Comment: LOL :D :D :D there is NO WAY and people keep asking :D As of today there still is NO WAY https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#user-data