# How to request additional claims with Facebook authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, facebook-login

I have created a new ASP.net Core 3.0 website, with individual user authentication from the .net project template.

I am storing users by registering directly on the site or using facebook.  Here's what my `Startup.cs` looks like:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => {
           // This determines user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
           options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
           options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
      });

      services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
           options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
      });

      services.AddAuthentication()
           //.AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions => {  })
           //.AddGoogle(googleOptions => {  })
           //.AddTwitter(twitterOptions => {  })
           .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
           {
               facebookOptions.AppId = "x";
               facebookOptions.AppSecret = "y";
           });

    ...
}
```

This all works fine and using the default template I can Register/Login as expected.

When I login via Facebook, I'm given five default pieces of claims information about the user:

- name identifier
- email address
- given name
- name
- surname

What I need to do is extend the code so it does more than the default and gives me access to the users:

- phone number
- address
- postcode

(Obviously with the users consent)

I've been reading the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1) but it seems to be more about configuring the authentication provider than additional claims info.

Has anyone done this?  Maybe it's not possible?

Thanks for any pointers in advance.

Comment: Is it not `facebookOptions.Scope`? Though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47901211/3181933) suggests that you can't get phone number. Not sure about address and post code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: [Persist additional claims and tokens from external providers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-3.1) - If the app requires additional scopes, add them to the options. For example, in Facebook, you can add scopes like this.

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
{
    facebookOptions.AppId = "4387237897237";
    facebookOptions.AppSecret = "23498423808320849082308";
    facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
    facebookOptions.Scope.Add("user_location");
    facebookOptions.Scope.Add("user_birthday");
});
```

Which will show details like this - login screen more details.

[image: Facebook authentication dialog]

Comment: I think this is almost what I need.  What would the equivalent of this be for the facebook api?  I'd like to request the `user_location` claim, for example, mentioned in the api reference (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions).  What would the schema be when adding the scope for it?  Thanks!

Comment: Updated the answer with Facebook-specific permissions.