# Login with Facebook, email not found

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I developing a Login/Inscription with Facebook to my website, and sometime some persons can't register with it.

So, I saw my logs that contains this sentence " `Email not found` " that happing when I want to get the email from the Facebook response API.

The code :

```
FB.api('/me',
    {fields: "email,first_name,last_name"},
      function(response) {

    });
```

But the problem, it's work with 80% of persons, and with some search and filtering, I found that this problem happing when the user does his inscription with phone number os when he/she didn't activate the email.

The problem here is I need the Email for some reason ( The contact with the user if he/she win).

is there any solution?

Comment: Ask the user to fill in an email address

Comment: @WizKid this can be good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix the problem, the best way is to ask the new user to add Email when he/she registered.

I try to get the phone number if the email not found, but Facebook doesn't give permission to get it.

More information about that : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11049017/6173086